# Does the damage of a melee weapon, displayed in the pipboy reflect the damage of a regular attack or power attack?

Tags: fallout-4

In the pipboy a melee weapon's damage is shown, but i'm not sure whether that damage is from a regular or power attack.

On a similar note, does holding down the attack button for melee weapons the equivalent of doing a power attack by simply pressing ALT? (going by default controls)

Comment: [The wiki mentions](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance#For_Close_Combat_Damage) that the attack modifier for power attacks is 1.5, which leads me to believe that what is displayed in the pipboy is the regular attack. I don't think it would make much sense to display the power attack damage. Could be tested by comparing with a ranged wepaon that has similar damage stats and see if your mellee weapon does the same damage or does less damage on the same target.

Comment: Yeah when i think about it, it's probably just displaying regular attacks as you mentioned it would be silly to display power attack damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The displayed damage is the regular damage.** Power attacks do extra.

The Nukapedia page on [Melee Damage](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Melee_Damage) states that

> - Melee and Unarmed attacks in V.A.T.S. do twice as much normal damage, but this doubling is done before Strength is added.
> - Power attacks in real-time combat also double normal damage.

The damage was doubled in previous Fallout games, but the [Damage Resistance](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Damage_Resistance#For_Close_Combat_Damage) page says that, for close combat damage in Fallout 4,

> PowerAttackMulti = 1.5

So it's possible the multiplier may have changed. Regardless of the multiplier, power attacks do *more* damage, rather than normal attacks doing *less*.

Comment: Which makes sense. It wouldn't be quite intuitive (IMO) if they were displaying something that was literally not "regular".

Comment: @DangerZone Agreed. Someone thought it was worth asking, though.

Comment: Yeah thought it'd be at least worth asking to just double check. Didn't realise VATS doubled the damage though! Either way i am annoyed that the game (by default) doesn't use power attacks when clicking and holding the attack button like in Skyrim, that was more intuitive than pressing the left alt button.